# In Progress-4GL how do I set an object to accept different numbers of inputs?

Tags: oop, progress-4gl, openedge

using openedge 10.2.b
ItemObj.cls

```
CLASS mystuff.ItemObj :
  METHOD PUBLIC CHARACTER GetItemDesc
  ( INPUT pcOne AS CHARACTER,
  INPUT pcTwo AS CHARACTER,
  INPUT piThree   AS INTEGER ) :

    RETURN pcOne pcTwo pcThree.

END METHOD.
```

ItemObj.p

```
USING mystuff.*.
DEFINE VARIABLE rItemObj AS CLASS mystuff.ItemObj NO-UNDO.
rItemObj = NEW mystuff.ItemObj( ).
MESSAGE "One : " rItemObj:GetItemDesc (1)       SKIP(1)
        "Two : " rItemObj:GetItemDesc (1, 2)    SKIP(1)
        "Three : " rItemObj:GetItemDesc (1, 2, 3) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO.
DELETE OBJECT rItemObj.
```

I want the output of all these statements to be the same so that if a user enters only 1 input the other two default to 2 and 3 and the same if the user enter 1 and 2, three is defaulted to 3.

How do I do this without getting a mismatch parameters error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC Progress doesn't allow optional parameters in method definitions, so you'd have to create a method definition for each argument permutation or accept a data structure that handles multiple values as a parameter like a dynamic array, temp-table or custom object and unpack that (but then you're pushing logic onto your caller).

```
CLASS mystuff.ItemObj:
  METHOD PUBLIC CHARACTER GetItemDesc (INPUT pcOne   AS CHARACTER,
                                       INPUT pcTwo   AS CHARACTER,
                                       INPUT piThree AS INTEGER):
    RETURN pcOne pcTwo pcThree.
  END METHOD.

  METHOD PUBLIC CHARACTER GetItemDesc (INPUT pcOne   AS CHARACTER,
                                       INPUT pcTwo   AS CHARACTER):
    RETURN GetItemDesc(pcOne, pcTwo, 3).
  END METHOD.

  METHOD PUBLIC CHARACTER GetItemDesc (INPUT pcOne   AS CHARACTER):
    RETURN GetItemDesc(pcOne, "2").
  END METHOD.
END CLASS.
```

Comment: How would you handle the problem? I really don't want to support three difference version of the same object. Are there advantages in using a transportation object?

Comment: The dynamic array / temp-table solution is probably not very good as IIRC you can only have a single type for the entire data structure (e.g. only `INTEGER` or `CHARACTER`, no mixing). You can do something dumb like just use `Object` as the type and downcast the value to a specific type at runtime depending on which extent it is in, but... eww. I would use the solution I provided 90% of the time, and in the other cases where complexity is needed create some type of `Options` object and accept that. The best long-term solution is to find a better language than Progress to use. ;)

Comment: Also, if this code will only ever run on Windows then you might be able to write something more flexible in `.NET` by using the CLR bridge. But I don't have any experience with that, sorry.

Comment: You won't be supporting three different versions, just using one version to call the more detailed version like Abe wrote here.

Comment: Tim is right. You will only have one object - the class. And the effective coding of your method will only be in one place - the one with the 3 parameters. The other two methods will do nothing but call that one with default values, so the effect is the same as optional parameters. It's called method overloading and most languages use this. VB6 was one of the very rare languages that allowed true optional parameters, so this is not a weird Progress aberration or a bug or shortcoming. This is how you would do it in .NET as well.